# An easy question on unit and counit to an adjunction

Tags: category-theory

Let $F: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ be a functor and suppose that it admits a left adjoint $R: \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{A}$. Take next an object $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and consider the object $(F\circ R \circ F \circ R)(B)$. Which is the relationship between such an object $(F\circ R \circ F \circ R)(B)$  and the object $(F \circ R)(B)$?

I tried to understand it on books (mainly Borceux, Adamek), but I do not understand in effect what happens. Using the unit and the counit, we get the relations also given in the post:

[Equivalence of the definition of Adjoint Functors via Universal Morphisms and Unit-Counit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690971/equivalence-of-the-definition-of-adjoint-functors-via-universal-morphisms-and-un)

However, for proving theorems and for solving exercises, it is convenient to manipulate (and simplify, if possible) expression such $(F\circ R \circ F \circ R)(B)$ or $(R\circ F \circ R \circ F)(A)$ or similar. What about all these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\A}{\mathscr{A}}\newcommand{\B}{\mathscr{B}}$Ok, please don't call your *left* adjoints $R$!

I'm not really sure what you want from this vague question of "comparing" but let me offer some useful 'algebra' maps.

I'm going to use the notation $L:\B\rightleftarrows\A:R$ with the adjunction having variance $L\dashv R$ i.e. $L$ is the left adjoint and $R$ is the right adjoint. You're asking to compare $RLRL(B)$ with $RL(B)$. Let's use $T:=RL:\B\to\B$; this is the associated *monad* of the adjunction. You have $T^2(B)$ and this is related to $T$ with three canonical natural transformations: $$\eta_T:T\implies T^2,\,T\eta:T\implies T^2,\mu:T^2\implies T$$Where $\eta:1\implies T=RL$ is the adjunction unit and $\mu$ is the monad multiplication map, or more concretely $\mu=R\epsilon_L$ where $\epsilon:LR\implies1$ is the counit, $\epsilon_L:LRL\implies L$ and $\mu=R\epsilon_L:T^2=RLRL\implies RL=T$.

These three transformations relate to each other in the following way: $$\mu\circ\eta_T=1_T=\mu\circ T(\eta)$$And $\mu$ also satisfies: $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}T^3@>T\mu>>T^2\\@V\mu_TVV@VV\mu V\\T^2@>>\mu>T\end{CD}$$All this can be checked with the triangle identities and naturality of the unit, counit. These identities are, in general, part of the monad axioms. It seems that people care quite a bit about monads, so we should believe these are useful comparisons between $RLRL(B)$ and $RL(B)$.

Comment: Ah ok, it's clear. Using your notations, suppose now that $R$ is fully faithful. In such a case, the counit  $\epsilon: LR \implies 1$ s a natural isomorphism. Under such assumption, if I write $\eta_{RL(B)}: RL(B) \to RLRL(B)$, may I infer that $\eta_{RL(B)}$ is an isomorphism for every $B \in \mathcal{B}$?

Comment: @TheWanderer Yes, you may. 
One helpful intuition for $RL=T$ is to see it as a sort of projection, returning the thing “closest” to something coming from the other category $\mathscr{A}$. This is best exemplified in the case of a reflection-inclusion adjunction, which is basically your question. Then $T$ is an *idempotent* (monad), $T^2\cong T$, just as a projection is. To prove it, observe if $\epsilon$ is an isomorphism then so is $\mu=R(\epsilon_L)$ and therefore the right inverses to $\mu$, $\eta_T,T(\eta)$, are necessarily total inverses and the same. $\eta_T=T(\eta)$ is an isomorphism.